# Multiprocessing brute-forcer complexity improvement

Tags: python-3.x, queue, python-multiprocessing, brute-force, code-complexity

I am scripting a brute-forcer and would like to get advises in order to improve its efficiency by reducing its complexity.

I first used the `multithread` library but quickly realised that it was not suitable for CPU-basded tasks, therefore, I switched to the `multiprocessing` library and noticed a real improvement in the script execution time.

- There is a real improvement when jumping from one process (takes 4 minutes) to 8 processes (takes 46 seconds). Above 8 processes the script takes longer run, is that to be expected?
- I populate a `multiprocessing.Queue()` with the wordlist, then, I feed the processes with the queue. Would it be faster to directly read one line from the wordlist then process it straight away without using?

The method to populate the queue with the content of the wordlist:

```
def populate_queue(wordlist, verbose):
    """ Loads up the wordlist
        into the multiprocessing.Queue() 
    """
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    for entry in wordlist:
        if verbose:
            print(DEBUG + "Inserting into queue: " + Style.BRIGHT + entry.rstrip() + RESET)
        queue.put(entry.rstrip())

    return queue
```

The main method of my script:

```
def main():
     # Register the CTRL+C trap
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    global start_time

    args = parse_args()

    process_count = args.process_count
    token = args.token
    wordlist = args.wordlist
    verbose = args.verbose

    processes = []

    ## Variables summary
    print(INFO + "JWT: " + Style.BRIGHT + "{}".format(token) + RESET)
    print(INFO + "Wordlist: " + Style.BRIGHT + "{}".format(wordlist.name) + RESET)

    start_time = time.time()
    print("[*] starting {}".format(time.ctime()))

    # Load and segmentate the wordlist into the queue
    print(INFO + "Processing the wordlist..." + RESET)
    queue = populate_queue(wordlist, verbose)

    print(INFO + "Total retrieved words: " + Style.BRIGHT + "{}".format(queue.qsize()) + RESET)

    for i in range(process_count):
        process = Process(queue, token, verbose)
        print(INFO + "Starting Process #{}".format(i) + RESET)
        process.start()
        processes.append(process)

    print(WARNING + "Pour yourself some coffee, this might take a while..." + RESET)

    # Block the parent-process until all the child-processes finish to process the queue
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    if not exit_flag:
        print(RESULT + "No match found" + Style.RESET_ALL)

    end_time = time.time()
    print("[*] finished {}".format(time.ctime()))

    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print("[*] elapsed time {} sec".format(elapsed_time))
```

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: It's probably not going to be significantly faster, but you could use `multiprocessing.Pool` to handle starting up worker processes, and pass them jobs with the pool's `map` method. It works almost exactly like what you already have, but you could do it with about three lines of code.

Comment: @Blckknght could you provide please provide me a working example, I am not familiar at all with the multithreading library, also would it improve the script performance?